# Want to auto-resize jQuery UI.Layout's div width and height when resize the container of them using JQuery UI resizable!

Tags: jquery, layout, resizable

I am going to using [jQuery UI.Layout Plug-in](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/index.cfm) with **JQuery UI resizable** plugin.

[the container layout example of JQuery UI layout plugin:](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/container_centered.html)

My code struct like this:

html code:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="paddingWrapper" class="pane ui-layout-center">

        <div class="pane ui-layout-center">

            Center

            <p><a href="http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos.html"><b>Go to the Demos page</b></a></p>

        </div>

        <div class="pane ui-layout-north">North</div>

        <div class="pane ui-layout-south">South</div>

        <div class="pane ui-layout-east">East</div>

        <div class="pane ui-layout-west">West</div>

    </div>

</div>
```

and the **div id="container"** will be attached with **jquery ui resizable plugin** and **jquery ui draggable plugin**.

the code attach layout Ui plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#container').layout();

});
```

But it seems when I resize the **div id="container"**,the layout was broken.the **inner contents** also **preserve original with and height**.So, I need a way to make the layout of inner could auto resize when I resize the container of them.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't know this layout plugin, but it seems pretty interesting... Thanks!

Check out the [documentation](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/documentation.cfm#Properties_Methods) of the layout, there's is a method called resizeAll() "Resizes the entire layout to fit its container". I don't really get the example they give, but I guess you might want to use it. Otherwise you can call this function from the stop event of the resizable:

```
$("#container").resizable({
  stop: function(){
    $("#paddingWrapper").layout("resizeAll");
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems a resize function was called to re-fit all panel when I resize the browser window. But I didn't get resizeAll to work in div resizing

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot ! +1 from me :)